# how to make work ExecuteReader() method using sqlcommand without any exception or error?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am making a simple login Application using c# , for that i build a class for database connectivity and relative thing using sql-server-2012 i am using the methods given below what is the problem with this class even i have done bank program using these methods that works perfectly but it don't why ?

```
namespace Stock
{
    class Dbs
    {
        public Dbs()
        {
            connect();
        }

        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlDataReader dreader;
        DataTable dtbl;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlConnection connect()
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = stockdb ;Integrated Security = true");
            return connection;
        }

        public bool login(string username,string password)
        {
            bool ok = false;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from administrator", connection);
            connection.Open();
            // here exception occurs
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dreader.Read())
            {
                if (dreader["username"].ToString() == username && dreader["passwords"].ToString() == password)
                {


                    MessageBox.Show("welcome " + username + " login success ....!");
                    ok = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Get out of here...........");
                }
            }

            return ok;

        }



        }
}
```

Comment: and what is exception?

Comment: `Data Source = .;` ??????? what is the datasource here

Comment: EHSAN Sajjad the Exception is invalid object name

Comment: un-lucky Data Source = .; . is my sql server server name

Answer (score 1):

to check your code, I created a database named **stockdb** and created a table **administrator** and execute your code and found it is ok, no error. I can access data from database. I debug the code and took the screen shot where the program execution is inside and if block and setting **ok** variable by **true**. please have a look:

[image]